# Getting random maps from generator code in Scala

Tags: scala, random, functional-programming

I have the following code from the Coursera course Functional Program Design in Scala. It is supposed to be a generator of maps of Int to Int.

```
lazy val genMap: Gen[Map[Int, Int]] = for {
  k <- arbitrary[Int]
  v <- arbitrary[Int]
  m <- oneOf(const(Map.empty[Int, Int]), genMap)
} yield m.updated(k, v)
```

My problem is I don't know how to use it. Typing:

```
genMap.generate
```

does not work. So how can I get maps from Int to Int from this generator?

The trait Generator looks like this (according to the course lectures):

```
trait Generator[+T]{
  self =>
  def generate : T
  def map[S](f:T=>S):Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
    def generate = f(self.generate)
  }

  def flatMap[S](f:T=>Generator[S]):Generator[S] = new Generator[S]{
    def generate = f(self.generate).generate
  }
}
```

Comment: Got the code around too? Can't answer the question without seeing the `Gen` trait.

Comment: So `generate` looks right. Now I would suggest https://scalafiddle.io/ or http://scastie.org/ to reproduce your error - also make sure your code is all here to prevent link rot.

Comment: If all you want is one generated Map you can use `genMap.sample`

Comment: Are you trying this in scala workscheet? Eliplse/jIdea?

Comment: @PavelOliynyk yes I'm trying it from IntellijIdea

Comment: @Taig in fact you're right

Comment: Did you implement arbitrary and oneOff ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `genMap.sample` to have a single instance generated. `sample` does return an `Option` though, in case it is not possible for your `genMap` to generate a valid instance.

When using `sample` in test code I usually just proceed by calling `Option.get` letting the test crash if no instance can be generated. This indicates that your `Gen` definition is too strict.